# Using Eliza chat bot with java application

Tags: java

I am using the Eliza chat bot to find a reply to a string, and I found [this](http://codeanticode.wordpress.com/2007/11/12/eliza-library-for-processing/) library to help with that. Here is my code so far:

```
package chatTest;

import codeanticode.eliza.*;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{   
    Eliza eliza;
    eliza = new Eliza(this);

    String response = eliza.processInput("Hello");
    System.out.println(response);

}
}
```

However, this gives me two errors:

```
Main.java:13: error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
            eliza = new Eliza(this);
                              ^
Main.java:13: error: cannot access PApplet
            eliza = new Eliza(this);
                    ^
  class file for processing.core.PApplet not found
2 errors
```

I don't know what the 'this' is meant to refer to, and I don't know what it is asking about a PApplet. Also, If there is a better way to do this (Perhaps with the original, unmodified Eliza), that would also be appreciated. And, if there is another, better downloadable chat bot than Eliza (I could only find Eliza to download), I would like to know about it.

Comment: It's your code. Why did *you* use `this`, given that you don't know what it's meant to refer to, and that it's causing you problems?

Comment: What am I meant to use instead of this

Comment: I see. You copied [this example.](http://codeanticode.wordpress.com/2007/11/12/eliza-library-for-processing/) That snippet/library is meant for use in a [Processing](http://www.processing.org/) application, which is why you're getting error messages about `processing.core.PApplet`.

Comment: Ok, how should I implement the library then. Or is there a way to implement the [original](http://chayden.net/eliza/Eliza.html)

Answer (score 0):

Chatter-bot API allows you to use Pandorabots and I think there are a few Eliza implementations hosted on that website.

http://code.google.com/p/chatter-bot-api/

Comment: The reason I am using a DOWNLOADABLE library is so it can be run anywhere. I have already looked ad that API.